# Center div vertically and adapt font size

Tags: html, css

I need to display a gallery of images where over each image I have an icon and a number.

These elements are inside an overlay DIV which shows when the mouse is over.

I am trying to do two things:

1. The vote div should be vertically aligned inside the overlay div;
2. I would like the heart font size to adapt depending on the image width.

Can these two problems be solved?

My code and [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8rx071p7/48/):

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="vote">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                <span>350</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="vote">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                <span>350</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="vote">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                <span>350</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="vote">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                <span>350</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="vote">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                <span>350</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div> 

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: box-model;
  -moz-box-sizing: box-model;
  box-sizing: box-model;
}

*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.gallery {  
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {    
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {   
    .image {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;  
  max-width: 100%;
  outline: 0; 
}

.overlay {    
    background-color: #404040;      
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;      
    font-size: 0.75rem;      
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;        
    top: 0;      
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;    
}

.image:hover .overlay {
    display: block;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: 0.8;    
}

.vote {
}

.vote a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.vote i {     
    color: red;   
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.0;
    font-size: 8rem;             
}

.vote span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Are you consider javaScript?

Comment: Here you have the vertically aligned vote div: http://jsfiddle.net/Kirito/8rx071p7/50/ How much % of the div width should the font size be?

Comment: The font can be 30% of the div. Then I can adjust

Comment: I just edited my answer below to include a pure CSS solution that sets your font-size to 30% of the div.

Answer (score 1):

You can center the `vote` class like this:

```
.vote {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

See http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ for how this works.

Scaling the font is trickier since you're using font-awesome.  I don't think you can do so with CSS.

Here's a JavaScript solution, which sets the font-size as 30% of the height of each image:

```
var images= document.querySelectorAll('.image');

for(var i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++) {
  var height= images[i].offsetHeight;
  var heart= images[i].querySelector('.fa');
  var span= images[i].querySelector('span');
  heart.style.fontSize= span.style.fontSize= (height*0.3)+'px';
}
```

### Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Ok, #1 is easy: there are multiple possible solutions. Actually was a a really good extensive article about that on the internet some time ago: [Vertical Centering With CSS](http://web.archive.org/web/20140209133455/http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

Or, you could use a modern solution like flexbox:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Centered vertically and horizontally
  </div>
</div>


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Please remember to include prefixed versions for that if and where needed and check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) to see what browsers don't support this solution before deploying it.

As for #2: Took me quite some time to figure out that it's actually much easier than I thought:

```
.vote {
  font-size: 30vw; 
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {   
  .vote {
    font-size:15vw;
  }
}
```

Adjust the value to your liking. Again: Viewport units are not totally supported by all browsers (*cough IE cough*), please check caniuse. I don't have a copy of IE handy just now, but I think vw should be supported, so I see no problems here. And keep in mind that Safari on iOS does some weird stuff, although to my knowledge that only affects vh and not vw.

Comment: Flexbox is perfect for centering, but I don't think `vw` will work, because it's relative to the view-port rather than the parent container.  Font-awesome complicates things, and I don't think there's a CSS-only solution.

Comment: I agree, vw alone is not an all-purpose solution. But MDMoura provided a fiddle in which the parent container is always exactly 100% or 50% of the viewport. My solution works based on that assumption, check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/a3vmx4jq/1/ (removed the hover so you can see the scaling better)

Comment: Yes, it's a great solution given the HTML as posted.  Since OP wrote, "depending on the image width," there may be images of different sizes on his production site.

Comment: In that case you're right, as long as we have no variables in CSS, it's probably not possible to solve that without JS.